# my Sql query to select 2 records per each category

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. 1. news table 2. category table.

in news table i have id, title, category id 
in category table i have id and category name.

in news table there are many news items where multiple news items for each category.

what i need was to select 2 record per each category from news table, also i need to join those two tables, so that i can get the name of the category from category table.
i tried using below query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
            news.id, news.fk_lookups_category, lookups_category.name, news.title, news.description,news.datetime,lookups_category.priority
        FROM news
            JOIN lookups_category ON news.fk_lookups_category=lookups_category.id
        WHERE
            news.isPublished='1' and news.datetime >= ('today' - INTERVAL 7 day) order by datetime DESC
) as newitem order by priority
```

Comment: Can you show an example of 2 tables

Comment: My news table has the fields                                                                         1 id 

 2 title 

 3 description

 
 4 datetime 

 
 5 fk_lookups_category 

 6 isPublished                                                                                    category table has 1. id 2. name 3. priority

Comment: Can you select some rows and edit your question please. @Fazil

Comment: see my query.. from this query i am getting all the news items for seven days according to their priority...but i am confused with how to select only 2 items per each category @alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: can some one explain me using my query.. to select 2 items per each category..

Comment: I gave you a link. Have you checked that out?